What are the values of an intersection type in Java?
I don't understand this passage in the Java Language Specification :
JLS § 4.9:

The values of an intersection type are those objects that are values
of all of the types Ti for 1 ≤ i ≤ n.

As far as I know, it is not possible to directly declare that a variable's type is an intersection type.
The place where I have seen the intersection type used is in the declaration of generic classes, but this seems to have nothing to do with the values of the intersection type.
So what do the values of the intersection types mentioned here refer to?
Besides, what is meant by "those objects that are values of all of the types Ti"?

Do you understand what I mean if I say "the values of byte are integers from -128 to 127"? That's what "the values of ...." means here.

Instead of "values", perhaps "inhabitants" is easier to understand for you?

Since interjections define at most 1 class and several interfaces. That means the values will have to have all those types, i.e. be a subclass of the concrete class and implement all of the interfaces.

Re: "The place where I have seen the intersection type used is in the declaration of generic classes": The section of the spec that you link to mentions several other uses (in the second paragraph).

@Sweeper Although I am a beginner, I understand what you mean. But why can an object be called a value?

@user24723440 Does it make more sense if it said "references" instead of "objects"? References are values of reference types, as the beginning of chapter 4 says.

@Sweeper  Uh... 4.3.1 says, "An object is a class instance or an array." , "The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects." , If it says “references” here, I would understand it because it is indeed a value. But an object may not be a references?

Yeah, objects are not references. I think this is just some sloppy writing in the JLS. I don't think this affects any other part of the spec anyway.

@Sweeper I wouldn’t call it sloppy. Using the term “value” at this place allows to make the statement as general as possible, even if today’s Java only supports reference types in intersection types in practice.

@Holger The dispute is not about "value". It's about the usage of "object". The JLS says that "objects" are the values of an intersection type, but it was already established that the values of reference types are references, not objects. In other words, the phrase "those objects that are values of all of the types Ti" doesn't make sense. The values of Ti does not include any objects.

@Sweeper oh yes, any other placeholder word like “thing” would have been better than a word with a predefined formal meaning. Though, after reading the sentence again, the entire phrase “are those objects that are” feels awkward to me. I think, the statement that should be at this place should say something about which values may be compatible with the intersection type. Which, of course, are references, including the null reference which doesn’t point to an object at all.

Consider the following code:
public class IntersectionDemo {

    interface T1 {
    }

    interface T2 {
    }

    static <T extends T1 & T2> void foo(T t) {
    }
    
    static class V implements T1, T2 {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(new V());
    }
}

Here the variable t has the intersection type of T1 and T2 and can  accept only reference to object that implements both T1 and T2, for example reference to object of type V.

The type of t is clearly not an intersection type. It is the type variable T. An example of a variable having an intersection would be something like var t = (T1 & T2)new V();.

To elaborate on Sweeper's comment . . . consider  static <T extends T1 & T2, U extends T1 & T2> void foo(T t, U u) { t = u; }, which is invalid, because types T and U are different, even though both have the same bounds.

@Sweeper Generics in Java are not types, they are just syntactic sugar that does not exist in the bytecode.

Sure they do not exist in bytecode, but we are talking about the Java language here, not the JVM. If we are talking about the JVM, intersection types do not exist either. The type of t, as far as the JVM is concerned, is its erasure T1.

@Sweeper Give an example of type intersection within versions of Java that did not have var.

I'm not sure what your point is but the type of the expression (T1 & T2)new V() is already an intersection type.

@Sweeper What type should the variable be that you assign this value to?

If you really want to tackle the "intersection type" problem, better is to read https://nipafx.dev/java-var-intersection-types/

Why does it matter? The type can be any type that has a conversion from the intersection type T1 & T2 in an assignment context. That aside, I think your misunderstanding is that all types must have names that can be written in source code. This is not true. The concept of a "type" is abstract, not a syntactic construct.

@Sweeper You are off topic, I claim that variable t has the intersection type of T1 and T2, and you cannot prove otherwise.

JLS 8.4.1: "If the formal parameter is not a variable arity parameter, then the declared type is denoted by UnannType if no bracket pairs appear in UnannType and VariableDeclaratorId". It does not say anything to the effect of "if UnannType is a type variable, then the declared type is the intersection of the bounds of that type variable".

JLS §4.9: "Intersection types can be derived from type parameter bounds (§4.4) and cast expressions (§15.16)". So, in the code <T extends T1 & T2> void foo(T t), the variable t has the intersection type of T1 and T2, and in the expression (T1 & T2) new V(), the reference to an object of type V is cast to the intersection type of T1 and T2.

Just try static <T extends T1 & T2> void foo(T t) { t = (T1&T2)null; } The compiler will reject it because the type of t is not just an intersection type of T1 and T2 but the distinct type T.


As far as I know, it is not possible to directly declare that a
variable's type is an intersection type.

Right, you cannot express an intersection type outside generic context.
But you can create object whose type conforms to some intersection type:
class K implement Serializable, Cloneable {...}
var k = new K();

Beware that k type is not intersection type, it is K.
But it conforms to an intersection type:
class C {
    public static <T extends Serializable & Cloneable> void f(T t) {
    }
}
C.f(k);


those objects that are values of all of the types

All instances of classes that implements both Serializable and Cloneable are values of all the types.
C.f(k) is correct because type of k K conforms to the contract: be both Serializable and Cloneable.
class C {
    public static <T extends Serializable & Cloneable> void f(T t) {
        var a = (Serializable & Cloneable)t;
        t = a; // Wrong!
    }
}

Local variable a is of the intersection type.
And the intersection type is different from T.
